# Invalid operand type was used: array_uintersect expects array(s)

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5, hhvm, array-intersect

I have the following code that get the intersection on a variable amount of arrays.

`$intersection = call_user_func_array('array_uintersect', $params);`

Using test data, this works very well.  However, when using real data (which is a much larger data set, using the same code, but running on `hhvm` and `nginx`, I get the following error when **comparing three or more arrays**:

`Invalid operand type was used: array_uintersect expects array(s)`

Comparing **two arrays** works fine.

I've checked the output of `$params` on the server, and it definitely has the correct values.  All elements of `$params` are arrays and the last element is an array with the value: `array_compare` which is the name of my custom array comparison function.

What could be causing this error?

**UPDATE:**

I updated HHVM to the latest nightly version and also upgrade my server's memory just to see if it would help.  However, it did not.

**UPDATE:**

I realize now that Laravel Homestead does not use `hhvm` by default, and after turning it on:

```
sites:
- map: homestead.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/project
  hhvm: true
```

The error was reproduced using my test data as well.  When turning hhvm off, the intersection works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in HHVM. I took the liberty of filing an issue for you: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/5585 You can follow along there for more updates.